# Add props to a children component

Tags: reactjs

Maybe a dumb question, but how can I add props to a children component?

I.e., I created this component:

```
import React, { useState } from "react";
import { Menu, MenuItem } from "@material-ui/core";

export default function DashboardMenu({ children }) {
    const [open, setOpen] = useState(false);
    const [anchorEl, setAnchoEl] = useState(null);
    const handleClick = event => {
        setAnchoEl(event.currentTarget);
        setOpen(!open);
    };

    const handleClose = () => {
        setOpen(false);
    };

    return (
        <>
            {children}
            <Menu
                id="configMenu"
                keepMounted
                anchorEl={anchorEl}
                open={open}
                onClose={() => handleClose()}
            >
                <MenuItem onClick={handleClose}>Profile</MenuItem>
                <MenuItem onClick={handleClose}>My account</MenuItem>
                <MenuItem onClick={handleClose}>Logout</MenuItem>
            </Menu>
        </>
    );
}
```

I can call it like this:

```
<DashboardMenu>
  <Avatar
    style={{
      backgroundColor:
         theme.palette.secondary.main
    }}
  >
     {avatarId}
  </Avatar>
</DashboardMenu>
```

And the component will render the `<Avatar>` component with the `style` props.

My question is, inside the `DashboardMenu` component, how can I add one more props to the children, like `{children onClick={handleClick}}`?

Comment: If you want to get the handleClick function to get work for children you can do something like this:

`<div onClick={handleClick}>{children}</div>`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `React.cloneElement` (doc [here](https://reactjs.org/docs/react-api.html#cloneelement)). You can pass `props` in the 2nd argument :

```
//...
return (
        <>
           {React.cloneElement(children, {/* props you want to add here*/})}}
            <Menu
                id="configMenu"
                keepMounted
                anchorEl={anchorEl}
                open={open}
                onClose={() => handleClose()}
            >
                <MenuItem onClick={handleClose}>Profile</MenuItem>
                <MenuItem onClick={handleClose}>My account</MenuItem>
                <MenuItem onClick={handleClose}>Logout</MenuItem>
            </Menu>
        </>
    );
```

You can find many examples of this in Material-UI such as [here in MenuList](https://github.com/mui-org/material-ui/blob/v4.9.2/packages/material-ui/src/MenuList/MenuList.js#L240).